# Custom operator for SDL

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class, it have a operator which returns a SDL_Renderer

```
class renderer {
public:
  explicit renderer(SDL_Window *window);
  ~renderer() = default;

  operator const SDL_Renderer *() const;

private:
  renderer_ptr _renderer;
};
```

I would like to use it on a SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface.

```
SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(r, surface)
```

Where r is `const std::shared_ptr<renderer> r`

I tried other ways, like

```
SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(r.get(), surface)
```

and

```
SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(*r, surface)
```

But no luck.

I remember that this used to work, but nowadays my C++ skills have rusted.

How can I use this operator while using a shared_ptr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shared_ptr overrides operators `* ->` to act like a normal pointer, you just need to dereference your shared pointer `*r`, the result is  of type `renderer`, which gets implicitly converted by your operator into an `SDL_Renderer *`.

[example](https://godbolt.org/z/3jhx7EoPY)

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    int x = 5;
    operator int*()
    {
        return &x;
    }
};
void fun(int* t)
{
    std::cout << *t << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> p = std::make_shared<A>();
    fun(*p);
}
```

Comment: With `*` I got this error: no known conversion from 'renderer' to 'SDL_Renderer *' for 1st argument. Is it expected?

Comment: @Rodrigo your function expects non-const pointer, you have a const pointer conversion, remove the const from your conversion.